# Is there any way to send a value to reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reduce

hey guys I'm trying to learn redux and in my component I have a value and need to pass it to my reducer.

here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import Iframe from "react-iframe";
import { Row, Col, Card} from "react-bootstrap";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import TextsInput from "./TextsInput";
import ImagesInput from "./ImagesInput";

import Aux from "../../hoc/_Aux";

class Frames extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
          <Col md={7}>
            <Iframe
              url={this.props.url}
              width= {this.props.width}
              height= {this.props.height}
              id= {this.props.id}
            />
            {this.props.inputs.map(( i, index) =>
            <TextsInput
            key={i.index}
            id={i.id}
            name={i.name}
            placeholder={i.placeholder}
            newText={i.newText}
            clicked={this.props.handleChange}
            />)}
          </Col>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    handleChange: () => dispatch({type: 'NEWINPUT'})
  }
};

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Frames);
```

I want to send frame id to my reducer, how can I do it?
thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include the `id` as part of your payload, as part of your action corresponding to `NEWINPUT`.

First and foremost, you will need to update your actions and reducer such that it takes in the additional payload, `id` (frame id).

Then, on your `mapDispatchToProps`, you will need to make sure that it accepts the id as a parameter. You will have to pass the `id` to your `handleChange` props too.

```
class Frames extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
          <Col md={7}>
            <Iframe
              url={this.props.url}
              width= {this.props.width}
              height= {this.props.height}
              id= {this.props.id}
            />
            {this.props.inputs.map(( i, index) =>
            <TextsInput
            key={i.index}
            id={i.id}
            name={i.name}
            placeholder={i.placeholder}
            newText={i.newText}
            clicked={this.props.handleChange(i.id)}
            />)}
          </Col>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    handleChange: (id) => dispatch({ type: 'NEWINPUT', id })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send payload while dispatching the action.

```
<TextsInput
   ...
   clicked={e => this.props.handleChange(e, i.id)}
   />
```

in mapDispathToProps

```
handleChange: (e, id) => dispatch({type: 'NEWINPUT', payload: {id, event: e}})
```

For more detail see [this](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions/#actionsjs) for action payloads and see [this](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) for using payloads in reducer.